# UIActionSheet presented using Popover causing issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uialertcontroller

#### Issue

I'm having issues with `UIAlertController`. It's an iPad project, in that I have two classes, say First and Second.

I'm presenting Second from First, using a modal presentation. In Second Class I have a button, clicking on that I'm showing UIActionSheet to perform some actions. It works perfectly except if user clicks on the button rapidly the Second class is being dismissed.

#### Code

**First VC:**

```
- (IBAction)showNext:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Second VC:**

```
- (IBAction)showActionSheet:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                     message:nil
                                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    [alertVC addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"LogOut"
                                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                        {
                        }]];
    
    [alertVC addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Update"
                                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                        {
                        }]];
    
    [alertVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
    
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alertVC popoverPresentationController];
    popPresenter.sourceView                       = sender;
    popPresenter.sourceRect                       = sender.bounds;
    [self presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

No other code in both classes. I don't know why it happens, Actually it happened to one of my Client project, So I created a test app with above code and it's also causing the issue.

#### Screen Capture

[image: Issue]

#### What I have tried:

1. I checked [UIAlertController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController)
2. Did a search on Google,, nothing came up

#### Alternatives:

1. If I set Second class as my `rootViewController`, the issue won't be there (But I can't do that, I need to navigate back and forth)
2. If I disable the popover dismissal when touched outside, it can avoid the issue. But I need this workflow.

Can anybody please help me ? I'm totally lost at this moment, not getting any useful info.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the view controller stack to me, have you tried altering the presentation of secondVC so it's in a UINavigationController?

Comment: @Jef: I don't think so. It's a Single View application (Added an extra vc, added the above mentioned code) nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the issue, but I fixed it. I used `popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover` and returned `YES`.

```
- (BOOL)popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController;
{
    return YES;
}
```

**Eureka:**

It was an accident!!! I didn't get any other way to fix this issue, so I thought will do the second alternative. While writing I accidentally wrote `YES` instead of `NO`. But it worked, I don't know how it worked and what is the reason for that issue.